# Date input in codeigniter (d-m-Y)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I'm stuck to input date to database.

I've already created helper with format day month Year, and it's work.
But I don't know how to use it to create date in database.
Give me an example of view and controller.

Thanks!

> helper tanggal_helper.php

```
    if (!function_exists('bulan')) {
        function bulan(){
            $bulan = Date('m');
            switch ($bulan) {
                case 1:
                    $bulan = "Januari";
                    break;
                case 2,3,4,5,6,....12
            }
            return $bulan;
        }
    }


    if (!function_exists('tanggal')) {
        function tanggal() {
            $tanggal = Date('d') . " " .bulan(). " ".Date('Y');
            return $tanggal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: pls be precise ,what is ur exact problem

Comment: my problem is. i cant insert date format d-m-Y in database

Comment: this is because mysql support date format Y-m-d enter date in this format

Comment: can i change the format or what? because i need to input data 'date' and show the data 'data' in d-m-Y format

Comment: yes u can show date whatever format u like but to store in mysql convert   date in Y-m-d format

Comment: you can also use a different column type, hell you could even use a text column to store it (not recommended)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to change your column data type to `varchar` and then use `date()` and `strtotime()` to insert date with your desired format

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('now')); // Current date
```

**OUTPUT**

```
07-06-2018
```